I checked myself vs I caught myself
I noticed that 'I checked myself'(definition 5) and 'I caught myself' seem to have similar meanings.
Example sentences are
He grinned, and then checked himself, not wanting to upset Jack.
I was about to correct him, but I caught myself in time.
Are the 'catch' and 'check' interchangeable in this context?  If they are, what are the nuances of each?
And if there is any, could you give an example sentence  where it is not interchangeable?
Thank you very much.

Your examples are from a dictionary. You'll notice each word has many definitions. The ones that aren't common or similar for both words are ones that aren't interchangeable.

For the relevant definitions of each word, in use cases like the two example sentences in your question, the words "catch" and "check" can usually be used interchangeably for practical purposes. But, there is a subtle distinction in meaning that may (or may not) be significant, depending on what you're trying to convey:
If you catch yourself doing something (like grinning, in your example), the literal meaning is just that you become aware that you're doing it. If you then realize the action may not be well received, this gives you the option to cease and desist! But, on its own, "catch" does not inherently convey the meaning of discontinuing the action, only of noticing it.
"Check" is the other way around. If you check yourself from doing something, it means you have decided against doing that thing - i.e., you were about to grin, but then decided not to. Logically, in order to consciously choose not to do something, you must first be aware of the action, so it implies the same sense of 'becoming aware of your own [involuntary or automatic] behavior' as "catch" can. However, the 'realization' part isn't intrinsic to the meaning of the word "check" any more than the 'not actually do [action]' part is to "catch."
The only reason the two verbs can often be used interchangeably is that the connotation of the usage in your example sentences allows the reader to supply additional context. If it is specified that a person caught themself doing something, the implication is usually that it was an unwanted or socially unacceptable involuntary action (like smirking). And, as before, if they checked themselves from doing the thing, you can assume they must have been aware of what they were doing (or of what they would have done).

An example where "catch" and "check" are not interchangeable: "Kevin caught himself smirking at his boss' remark during the meeting, but didn't bother to conceal his amusement." Here, Kevin's lack of manners makes the difference in meaning significant! It would not be an equivalent sentence if I had instead written "Kevin checked himself from smirking at his boss' remark during the meeting, but didn't bother to conceal his amusement." As matter of fact, the second sentence doesn't even make sense :)

Thank you Quack E. Duck very much for explaining in detail.  Your comment of the not interchangeable case helps me understand the differences better.

The phrases "checked myself" and "caught myself" are not exactly the same, but are interchangeable in some contexts.
Using "checked myself" to mean "stopped myself" or "changed my action" is not the only usage. You might also say "I checked myself for signs of insect bites." In that phrase, "checked" has the meaning "reviewed" or "looked over" myself.
The phrase "I caught myself" can mean "I stopped myself" or "I (suddenly or unexpectedly) became aware." These are not exactly the same.
"I caught myself eating a second piece of candy" does not mean you stopped eating, just that you became aware you were eating, without consciously thinking about it.
"I caught myself before I said the wrong thing" means you stopped yourself from saying something.
"I caught myself before I fell" probably means you physically grabbed something to keep from falling; this is another use with the sense of "stopped myself."
So, as for an example of the words not being interchangeable (because of different senses of "checked" and "caught"):
"I checked myself in the mirror" -- I looked at my reflection, reviewing how I looked.
"I caught myself before drinking the poison" -- I stopped myself before completing an action.

I caught myself in the mirror = I caught sight of myself in the mirror... (by chance, not as part of a deliberate "self-assessment" process) ...and realized that I had a bit of tissue paper stuck on a shaving cut.

Thank you user8356 for the comment.  I have been interested in comparing those 2 phrases primarily in the sense of 'stopping myself' suddenly or momentarily.  Thank you  FumbleFingers for comparing checked/caught myself in the mirror.
